# pdo/mysql create procedure

Tags: mysql, pdo, procedure

I'd like to create a procedure from PHP using PDO...I can execute the procedure with PDO, I can create the procedure with the console line or with phpmyadmin, but I'm not able to create this very same procedure from PDO...

I absolutely need to be able to create this procedure from my php code (it's a setup part of a bigger program, the first step checks if the procedure exists with

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS LIKE 'name_of_procedure'
```

if the procedure doesn't exists, I try (but fail) to create it (with prepare/execute couple of methods).

Comment: Solved that....I had to remove the delimiters...

Comment: You should actually answer your own question (instead of making a comment), then select your answer as the solution.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/31941239/175071