# Create Stored Procedures with PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pdo

I am reading a TEXT file from PHP and trying to execute commands from it, like creating a DB and all the tables and procedures it has. My code creates the tables but does not create Stored Procedures given in the file.

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_hits`$$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_hits`( In id varchar(255))
 BEGIN
 select hits into @hits from db_books where Book_ID = id;
 update db_books set hits=@hits+1 where Book_ID = id;
 END$$
```

The PDO is not creating the SPs, how will be able to accomplish this task?
I have tried executing all the code part together and line by line, but nothing works.
I am trying to make a DB installer script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, PMA Helped me with answering this Question of my own.
To overcome this you need to remove the delimiter part of the procedure, so that your queries become like:

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_hits`;
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_hits`( In id varchar(255))
 BEGIN
 declare hits_bk int;
 select hits into hits_bk from db_books where Book_ID = id;
 update db_books set hits=hits_bk+1 where Book_ID = id;
 END;
```

Now the queries will work.
Thanks to @Your Common Sense and @RiggsFolly for helping out.

Comment: Because PDO allows only one query per executions, you can do it with [Timo Huovinen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31941239/4721245)'s Solution by executing it one-by-one, preferably in transaction.

Answer (score 10):

PHP only allows you to execute one query at a time normally, so `$$` delimiters are not necessary.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$pdo->exec('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_hits`');
$pdo->exec('CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_hits`( In id varchar(255))
 BEGIN
 declare hits_bk int;
 select hits into hits_bk from db_books where Book_ID = id;
 update db_books set hits=hits_bk+1 where Book_ID = id;
 END');
```

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to keep on topic and answer the question

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_hits`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_hits`( In id varchar(255))
BEGIN
   select hits into @hits from db_books where Book_ID = id;
   update db_books set hits=@hits+1 where Book_ID = id;
END$$
```

The first occurance of `$$` will terminate the DDL so

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_hits`$$
```

So I think it should be

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_hits`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_hits`( In id varchar(255))
BEGIN
   select hits into @hits from db_books where Book_ID = id;
   update db_books set hits=@hits+1 where Book_ID = id;
END
$$
```

Comment: Now my Query is:
**DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_hits`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_hits`( In id varchar(255))
BEGIN
declare hits_bk int;
select hits into hits_bk from db_books where Book_ID = id;
update db_books set hits=hits_bk+1 where Book_ID = id;
END$$**
I have another procedure after this starting from:
    __DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_issues_num`;__
I am running the whole part together by the exec method.
But it still doesn't work.