# Can't create stored procedure mysql maybe if else syntax

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I try to write a stored procedure like this but it does not work:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_test`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_test`(
  IN my_in_var VARCHAR(255),
  OUT my_out_var VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  IF(in_var == 'my_in_value') THEN
    SET my_out_var = 'my_out_value1';
  ELSE
    SET my_out_var = 'my_out_value2';
  END IF;
END
```

I try to execute from php with PDO

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$mysql_host.";dbname=".$mysql_bd, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec($sql);
```

no errors but I can't see it on MySql server with

```
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE my_test
```

So I tried to copy paste it in the SQL window of phpmyadmin and I got this syntax error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'my_in_value') THEN
>   SET my_out_var = 'my_out_value1'' at line 6

What is the correct syntax? And why PDO not show the error ?

Any help is welcome - thanks

Comment: missing wrapping `DELIMITER` ?

Comment: have you try to use `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: yeah if you fix that it saves

Comment: you tried to execute what? the creation of it or running of it (that does not exist) via PDO?

Comment: btw you have no `in_var`

Comment: Drew delimiters not work with pdo ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409755/create-stored-procedures-with-pdo-in-php)
currarpickt I tried now = instead == . Not work
Drew I tried also in php $invar = "my_in_value" ... and pdo prepare - execute but not work ( no errors but not work ) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, it has been pointed out to me that the below `DELIMITER` is not necessary in PHPMyAdmin which I don't use. So, `DELIMITER` is a client thing, such as needed by the likes of MySQL Workbench.

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_test`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_test`(
  IN my_in_var VARCHAR(255),
  OUT my_out_var VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  IF (my_in_var = 'my_in_value') THEN
    SET my_out_var = 'my_out_value1';
  ELSE
    SET my_out_var = 'my_out_value2';
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
set @outme='';
call my_test('lizard',@outme);
select @outme;
-- my_out_value2

set @outme='';
call my_test('my_in_value',@outme);
select @outme;
-- my_out_value1
```

So you need to figure out what your intention is with the above.

You had a syntax error with the double `=`. And you were perhaps having a typo in the `in_var` that did not exist.

PHPMyAdmin (that does not require DELIMITER so I am told):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_test`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_test`(
  IN my_in_var VARCHAR(255),
  OUT my_out_var VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  IF (my_in_var = 'my_in_value') THEN
    SET my_out_var = 'my_out_value1';
  ELSE
    SET my_out_var = 'my_out_value2';
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: what I want is to set $my_in_value in PHP ... send it to SP and get @my_out_var value from SP back to use in PHP.
But first I need to create the stored procedure ... so first i try to sove that

Comment: Well there is probably no concept of @my_out_var with php in all of this. You will probably just have an in and out from PHP entirely. Why would there even be an @ var ... I was just showing that as an example calling it from inside a mysql client that needed to prove it

Comment: So, you write a stored proc. Wrap it in a bow. And it is callable from any decent environment like java, c#, PHP, python, etc

Comment: Ok. Thank's ... I have tried now and it work .. with PDO also ... I dont't know why ... before got error .... and [this post ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409755/create-stored-procedures-with-pdo-in-php) ... make me confused .